# Does the Dispel Magic spell work on magical weapons?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, weapons

Does casting *dispel magic* on a plain *+1 sword* make it no longer +1?   Also does *dispel magic* work on a *dragon slayer* longsword such that it is no longer +1 and no longer does extra damage against dragons?

Comment: [related] [does dispel magic work on skeletons, other undead...?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/92392/23970)

Answer (score 21):

## No, it doesn't.

[*Dispel magic*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dispel-magic) says that "any **spell** of 3rd level or lower on the target ends." (PHB p.234, followed by some provisos about higher levels. Emphasis mine.)

Your *+1 sword* is not a mundane sword currently under the effect of a *+1 to weapons* spell, it's just a magical item. A spell may have been used in its creation (see DMG pp.128-9), but there's no currently-active spell you can point to whose effect you'd be dispelling.

Answer (score 14):

## No, but Antimagic Field does

As [nitsua60's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/92398/does-the-dispel-magic-spell-work-on-magical-weapons/92399#92399) points out, [*dispel magic*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dispel-magic) only affects spells, and not magic items. But, as I've stated in my answer to [your other question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/92392/does-dispel-magic-work-on-skeletons-other-undead-and-constructs-like-golems), the [*antimagic field*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/antimagic-field) spell **does** do this:

> **Magic Items.** The properties and powers of magic items are suppressed in the sphere. For example, a + 1 longsword in the sphere functions as a nonmagical longsword.

It's important to note that *antimagic field* is not permanent, and any magical properties return outside of the field. It doesn't make sense that a relatively low-level spell, such as *dispel magic*, would be more powerful and permanent than the high-level *antimagic field*.

Answer (score -4):

Ah touche! Dispel Magic *does* indeed affect Magic Items, given that you can target *objects*. Which is what led me to this thread... There is no duration.

My interpretation of RAW is that it *could* destroy a magic item if the spell effect is less than 3rd level. If the spell effect is of unknown level, I assume you discern it via crafting level limits given in DMG or XGTE, and assume the lowest level of crafter... So a +1 Weapon *would* be a valid target.

All this being acknowledged, I think a fair RAI would be to say the item in question is instead "disabled" until a Short or Long Rest, especially if it's "bonded...

Comment: A DM could add a rule like that, but it isn't valid by rules as written. You can target objects, but it will only effect active spells on that object. If you cast light on a longsword +1 then cast dispel on it, you'd be left with a longsword +1.

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] for more information. This answer could be improved by included quotes from the rules you mention. Currently it is unclear which part you think are RAW and which are your interpretation.