# Can you Dispel animated dead?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, undead

Can you use the [*dispel magic*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dispel-magic) spell to take out undead that have been created using the *animate dead* spell?

As I understand it, [*counterspell*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/counterspell) is used to stop spells during their casting and *dispel magic* is for stopping active spells.

I know the animated dead doesn't need concentration or their caster to be alive after they have been animated, so the [*animate dead*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/animate-dead) spell might just turn a corpse into a undead type creature that no longer needs magic to be active.
 (I don't think the animate spells duration is relevant to this question.)

Comment: Somewhat related on [Does dispel magic affect skeletons and other undead?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/92392/does-dispel-magic-affect-skeletons-and-other-undead)

Comment: @delfiler please do not answer in the comments. See [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6533/should-users-refrain-from-answers-or-partial-answers-in-comments) for our policy. Thanks!

Comment: @NautArch Actually, with the edits this is very close if not a duplicate of your linked question, imho.

Comment: @Slagmoth Identical answer, but not identical question. That question is about standard MM skeletons/undead while this one is specifically about creatures created by a spell.

Comment: If the answer below satisfies your question adequately, consider hitting the 'accept' button.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

### No.

As indicated by the [Sage Advice Compendium (2017)](http://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf):

> **Can you use *dispel magic* on the creations of a spell like *animate dead* or affect those creations with *antimagic field*?**
>
> Whenever you wonder whether a spell’s effects can be dispelled or
>   suspended, you need to answer one question: is the spell’s duration
>   instantaneous? If the answer is yes, there is nothing to dispel or suspend.

So, yes, duration is entirely relevant.

The entry goes on to detail why it functions this way, to paraphrase though: the effect that animates the dead is instantaneously brought into being by magic, but is not continuously sustained by magic afterwards. Therefore, skeletons can enter an *antimagic* field at their leisure and hack you to bits.

**Of note**: *Danse macabre* has a duration on the spell and therefore you could dispel one of the animated creatures.

**Just for fun**, *if* *dispel magic* worked in this way it would be the most powerful spell in the game and here is why:

Anyone that has ever been the target of a *cure wounds* (or for that matter *revivify*, *raise dead*, *reincarnation*, *resurrection*, etc.) spell could potentially die outright if targeted by *dispel magic* since it would erase all previous curative effects in an instant.

Comment: While this answer is most certainly correct, it strikes me as odd to say that an animated corpse isn't sustained by magic. What *is* it sustained by, if not magic? An infinite supply of negative energy feels pretty magical to me.

Comment: @MichaelW. It may well be magic but what they refer to as "magic of the environment" like a Dragon's Breath. The "background" magic that infuses the "physics and physiology" of the world and its denizans are unaffected by such spells. p17 of the compendium goes into some detail on that. Under the question: Is the breath weapon of a dragon magical?

Comment: @MichaelW. Or to simplify, "dispell magic" dispells *spells*, not everything in the setting that isn't real-life based.  Spells are qualitatively different kind of "magic".

Comment: @Yakk So, *dispel magic* is actually just *de-spell*, huh?

Comment: @MichaelW. Crawford's responses on Twitter always start the same way on this topic. Dispel Magic does one thing, it ends spells.

Comment: Undead are animated by negative energy, same as the living being animated by positive energy. If you could disrupt negative energy, that'd pretty much make Paladins worthless, wouldn't it? Not to mention open the door to positive energy dispulsion.

Comment: @MichaelW. Or, rather, in this fantasy world, only spells are "magical".  Everything else is just this strange world's physics.  Including dragons breathing fire.